# Regular expressions in Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware-orion

I would like to know which set of Regular Expressions does the Orion Context Broker accept, as [the documentation](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/regex_in_payload/index.html) tells little details about that.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are used in two places:

- At MongoDB level in order to perform queries using the [$regex operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/), that is: *"Perl compatible regular expressions (i.e. "PCRE" ) version 8.39 with UTF-8 support"*.
- Internally in order to match expressions, using the [`regex.h` library](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regexec.3.html). We use `regcomp()` with `REG_EXTENDED` enabled, so the support here is POSIX Extended Regular Expression.

I'm not an expert in the different regex "dialects" but as far as I understand, PCRE supersedes POSIX Extended, so we can say that, as minimum, Orion Context Broker support POSIX Extended regular expressions.

Comment: Hi fgalan, So is there anyway to set expression flags for regex. In a special case, I want the regex case insensitive.

Comment: just one more thing, the regex does not apply for attribute has type là number is it right? i have an entity like this  {
            "type": "City",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "city1",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "mobilePhone",
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "0987876876"
                }
            ]
        }
  look like the regex does not working correctly. thanks

Comment: To which regex to you refer, please? In your last comment you only shows the entity, but not the regex you say is failing...

Comment: Sorry for the lacking of information, my regex is "phoneNumber ~= 7876". it will show all Citys in system. look like this regex not apply for number i guess. many thanks.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, I suggest to open a new question with your specific case. I mean, a question including: 1) the exact query you are doing, 2) an example of entity which is returned with that query and you think it shouldn't. Thanks!